# How do you implement the callOnclickByTag with the StatusBarNotification Phonegap plugin?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-intent, phonegap-plugins

Does anyone know how to call the onclick handler for the StatusBar Notification Phonegap plugin? The noftification I created is showing up in my status bar, but I would like to create a click event on the item in the status bar. My code currently looks like this:

```
window.statusBarNotification.notify('title', {
   body: 'body message',
   tag: 'download',
   onclick: function() {
     // handle click
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the onclick. In the plugin js the notify method looks like this:

```
NotificationMessenger.prototype.notify = function(title, body) {
    if (window.Notification) {
        this.activeNotification = new window.Notification(title, {
            body: body
        });
    }
}
```

I modified it to look like this:

```
NotificationMessenger.prototype.notify = function(title, options) {
    if (window.Notification) {
        this.activeNotification = new window.Notification(title, options);
    }
}
```

Now my code in the original question works.